# displaying data when using bootstrap framework

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have an edit form which `.form-horizontal` and `.control-label`. However, now I want to display one record to the user (for example, details of a users profile). So I envision something like this:

```
First Name:        Foo
Last Name:         Bar
Job:               Something
```

What is the best way to do this using bootstrap framework? I wanted to use the same structure as my edit form but since I'll be showing data, I can't used the `.form-horizontal` class. If I use the `<table>` tag then what class could I use?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

#### For Bootstrap 3

Bootstrap 3 provides a 'Horizontal Description' class to do present data exactly like you wish.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#horizontal-description

With your example data, you would do something like this:

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
  <dt>First Name</dt>
  <dd>Foo</dd>
  <dt>Last Name</dt>
  <dd>Bar</dd>
  <dt>Job</dt>
  <dd>Something</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that `dl-horizontal dt` in bootstrap 3 has a fixed width (160px), and when there is text overflow it uses ellipsis. You may need to override this css rule to show whole text when it is larger.

Comment: in bootstrap 4, dl-horizontal has been removed: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#typography

Answer (score 5):

#### For Bootstrap 4

You can use [**Description list alignment**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/typography/#description-list-alignment). For example-

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<dl class="row">
  <dt class="col-sm-3">Description lists</dt>
  <dd class="col-sm-9">A description list is perfect for defining terms.</dd>

  <dt class="col-sm-3">Euismod</dt>
  <dd class="col-sm-9">
    <p>Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper eget lacinia odio sem nec elit.</p>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</p>
  </dd>

  <dt class="col-sm-3">Malesuada porta</dt>
  <dd class="col-sm-9">Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.</dd>

  <dt class="col-sm-3 text-truncate">Truncated term is truncated</dt>
  <dd class="col-sm-9">Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</dd>

  <dt class="col-sm-3">Nesting</dt>
  <dd class="col-sm-9">
    <dl class="row">
      <dt class="col-sm-4">Nested definition list</dt>
      <dd class="col-sm-8">Aenean posuere, tortor sed cursus feugiat, nunc augue blandit nunc.</dd>
    </dl>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use table too here is for example

```
<table class=   "table table-user-information">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Dokter Umum:</td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->terap_addressdoc ?></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Specialist Chiropactic</td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->terap_specialist ?></td>
                  </tr>

                   <tr>
                    <td>Email</td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->terap_terapist ?></td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
              </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<dl class="row">
  <dt class="col-sm-3">Description lists</dt>
  <dd class="col-sm-9">A description list is perfect for defining terms.</dd>

  <dt class="col-sm-3">Euismod</dt>
  <dd class="col-sm-9">
    <p>Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper eget lacinia odio sem nec elit.</p>
    <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</p>
  </dd>

  <dt class="col-sm-3">Malesuada porta</dt>
  <dd class="col-sm-9">Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.</dd>

  <dt class="col-sm-3 text-truncate">Truncated term is truncated</dt>
  <dd class="col-sm-9">Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</dd>

  <dt class="col-sm-3">Nesting</dt>
  <dd class="col-sm-9">
    <dl class="row">
      <dt class="col-sm-4">Nested definition list</dt>
      <dd class="col-sm-8">Aenean posuere, tortor sed cursus feugiat, nunc augue blandit nunc.</dd>
    </dl>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).